# Are the WebViewPage classes that are generated for razor views in ASP.Net MVC stored in the file system?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

[According to Microsoft](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx), Razor views in ASP.Net MVC are converted to instances of the [System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) at run-time, when they are called for the first time.

Are these auto-generated classes stored in some temp directory in the file-system after they are generated for the first time at run-time?  If so, where are they stored?  Or do they only exist in memory and are not persisted to the file system, and thus it is not possible to see what the auto-generated class looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are these auto-generated classes stored in some temp directory in the
>   file-system after they are generated for the first time at run-time?

Yes.

> If so, where are they stored?

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

Adjust the .NET framework version you are using of course.

Answer (score 1):

Also see your `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\` folder.